# ReferenceError: response is not defined. I do not understand

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am new to coding and I don't understand how to fix this

My code:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  if (message.content === "meme"){
    let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
    let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
    let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
    let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
    let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
    let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
    let memeDownvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.downs;
    let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  got('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json').then(responses => {
  embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`)
  embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
  embed.setImage(memeImage)
  embed.setColor('RANDOM')
  embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeDownvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
  message.channel.send(embed);
  })
}
})
```

Console:
ReferenceError: Response is not defined

Comment: You defined the parameter as `message` so on line 3 when you say `response.body` it doesn't exist...instead it would be `message.body`

Answer (score 0):

`let content = JSON.parse(`**response.body**`);`

this response is not defined

use `message.body`

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you have:

```
let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
```

But on line one you have:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
```

So in fact `response.body` isn't defined since `response` isn't defined, instead use `message.body` since you named the parameter of your function `message`.

Line 1-3:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  if (message.content === "meme"){
    let content = JSON.parse(message.body);
```

Comment: ok but now (SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0) is showing so idk

Comment: `console.log(message.body)` the response might not be perfect JSON and will need to be messaged...or diagnosed @JFSdragonfire